# findstr in perl with escaping double quotes from piping

Tags: perl, findstr

Am trying to use findstr for which the input is from a pipe output which has quotes and the command is placed in a perl scropt. I couldnt match the double quotes . Eg: my out of java command is something like :

```
<violation beginline="30" endline="171" begincolumn="8" endcolumn="1" rule="something" ruleset="AllRules" package="com.mypackage priority="3">
<violation beginline="30" endline="171" begincolumn="8" endcolumn="1" rule="something" ruleset="AllRules" package="com.mypackage priority="5">

    our $currentViolationCount=`java Myclass | FINDSTR -i "priority=\"3\""`
```

I tried with FINDSTR -i ^"priority=\"3\"^" and also FINDSTR -i ^"priority=\^"3\^"^", but it doesnt match any line

Comment: `^` denotes the beginning of a line.

Comment: @devnull: In the Windows world `^` is a shell escape character.

Comment: Maybe it's easier (and more portable!) to avoid FINDSTR and do the string searching in perl.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl to process the output. Do not forget the error checking!

```
our $currentViolationCount=`java Myclass`;
if ($?){die "java Myclass is died, error: $!";}
my ($priority)=$currentViolationCount=~m!priority="\d+"!gis;
print "Found priority: $priority\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or as a cmdline oneliner:

```
java Myclass|perl -wnpi -e 's/.*priority="(\d+)".*/$1/g
```